# How do I implement a transition effect for navigation elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my navigation section a little nicer. Currently when I hover over the menu items to display the pages within, the pages show up instantly. I'd like them to show up gradually instead of all at once. I've tried adding `transition: 2s;` underneath `nav ul li:hover ul` in my CSS file, but that doesn't seem to work.

```css
header {
  color: #348899;
  background-color: #343642;
  background-image: url(Images/heading.png);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 42pt;
  line-height: 36pt;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 5px;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height: 22pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 5px 0;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height: 22pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
nav {
  color: #343642;
  background-color: #979C9C;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #343642;
}
nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  right: 35%;
}
nav ul li:hover ul  {
  display: block;
  transition: 2s;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background-color: #b1b6b6;
  width: 80px;
}
nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b1b6b6;
}
main {
  color: #17354A;
  background-color: #F2EBC7;
  margin-left: 160px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.column  {
  float: left;
}
.left {
  width: 75%;
}
.right {
  width: 25%;
}
.text {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
main .row .left {
  width: 25%;
}
main .row .left p {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
main .row .middle {
  width: 50%;
}
main .row .middle h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
main .row .right {
  width: 25%;
}
main .side .left {
  width: 50%;
}
main .side .right {
  width: 50%;
}
.brass {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.logo {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
body{
  background-color: #348899;
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
footer {
  color: #348899;
  background-color: #343642;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 160px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Beginning Band Players - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>
        Beginning Band Players
      </h1>
      <h2>
        Home
      </h2>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Brass</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Brass/trumpet.html">Trumpet</a></li>
            <li><a href="Brass/frenchhorn.html">Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="Brass/trombone.html">Trombone</a></li>
            <li><a href="Brass/euphonium.html">Euphonium</a></li>
            <li><a href="Brass/tuba.html">Tuba</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Woodwind</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Woodwind/clarinet.html">Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="Woodwind/flute.html">Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="Woodwind/oboe.html">Oboe</a></li>
            <li><a href="Woodwind/saxophone.html">Saxophone</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Percussion</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Percussion/bells.html">Bells</a></li>
            <li><a href="Percussion/snare.html">Snare Drum</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="misc/maintenence.html">Maintenence</a></li>
        <li><a href="misc/additional-equipment.html">Additional Equipment</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <div class="column left">
        <div class="logo">
         <img src="Images/Logo-E.png" alt="logo" height="200" width="355">
        </div>
        <h3>
         About us:
        </h3>
        <div class="text">
          <p>
            The purpose of Beginning Band Players is to provide students and parents
            with the necessary resources for a successful start in any band program.
            It's our hope that prospective music students find what they're looking
            for and enjoy a lifetime of music.
          </p>
          <div class="brass">
            <img src="Images/brass-1.jpg" alt="brass" height="238" width="425">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column right">
        <h3>
          What to Expect:
        </h3>
        <p>
          Students can learn a little about each instrument found in beginning band
          programs and decide which one they like best. They'll be able to see and
          hear what each instrument sounds like.
        </p>
        <h3>
          Additional Resources:
        </h3>
        <p>
          Students may also need additional equipment such as practice books or supplies
          to help maintain their instruments. Links to such supplies can be found on the
          Additional Equipment page.
        </p>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Copyright &copy; 2022, Carter Thomas Wolfe <br>
      Web Project Prototype
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the CSS which property you'd like to transition, and *how* you'd like it to transition. If you changed your transition line to something like:

```
 transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
```

That's saying: fade the opacity in over 2 seconds, with an "easing in" function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function That line above should work - but only if it has different states of opacity to transition between. Elements default to an opacity of 1, so simply defining the transition for opacity won't be enough, you have to also different states to change between. If you were using opacity, I'd try setting the default state for the element/class/whatever to 0, and the hover state to 1.

```
 .classYouWantToFadeIn {
      opacity:0;
      /*rest of the CSS*/
  }

  .classYouWantToFadeIn:hover {
      opacity: 1;
  }
```

If the transition still doesn't seem to work, read up on "specificity rules" in CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
nav ul li:hover ul  {
display: block;
transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}
```